# How to track computer wins and player wins until user quits?

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and I need help figuring out how to keep track of wins for both the computer and player until the player quits. I was thinking I could declare a variable globally but I am not sure if that would be good practice. This is what I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

// function declarations
int computerRoll();
int computerGuess();
void winner(int uGuess, int cGuess, int uSum, int cSum);

int main()
{  
// variable declaration
int userSum = 0, userGuess = 0, aiGuess = 0, aiSum = 0, play = 0;

while (true) {

    // ask user for sum of 3 dice rolls
    cout << "Enter the sum of your 3 dice rolls: ";
    cin >> userSum;
    cout << "\n\n";

    // check for correct user input
    while (userSum > 18 || userSum < 3)
    {
        cout << "\a\a\a Please enter a sum between 3 and 18: ";
        cin >> userSum;
        cout << "\n\n";
    }

    //computer guess
    aiGuess = computerGuess();
    cout << "The computer has guessed " << aiGuess << " For your number";
    cout << "\n\n";

    // computer rolls dice 3 times 
    aiSum = computerRoll();

    // User guesses the amount that was rolled by the computer
    cout << "Please guess the sum of the 3 dice rolls by the computer: ";
    cin >> userGuess;
    cout << "\n\n";

    // check for correct user input
    while (userGuess > 18 || userGuess < 3)
    {
        cout << "\a\a\a Please enter a sum between 3 and 18: ";
        cin >> userGuess;
        cout << "\n\n";
    }

    // Program determins winner/ keeps score
    winner(userGuess, aiGuess, userSum, aiSum);

    // ask user to keep playing or quit
    cout << "Enter any number to keep playing. Enter -1 to stop: ";
    cin >> play;
    cout << "\n\n";

    if (play == -1)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
return 0;
}

// simulate the computer rolling 3 dice, get sum
int computerRoll()
{
int srand(time(NULL));
int computerSum = 0;
const int MAX = 3;
int computerArray[MAX];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
// Just ignor the array for now, was just trying something out
    computerArray[i] = rand() % (6 + 1); 
    computerSum += computerArray[i];
}

return computerSum;
}
// simulate the computer guessing the sum of the 3 dice player has rolled
int computerGuess()
{
int srand(time(NULL));
int guess = 0;

guess = rand() % (18 + 1);

return guess;
}
// Get the difference in guesses
void winner(int uGuess, int cGuess, int uSum, int cSum)
{
int userDifference = 0;
int compDifference = 0;
int compWins = 0;
int userWins = 0;

if (uGuess >= cSum)
{
    userDifference = uGuess - cSum;
}
else if (uGuess <= cSum)
{
    userDifference = cSum - uGuess;
}
if (cGuess >= uSum)
{
    compDifference = cGuess - uSum;
}
else if (cGuess <= uSum)
{
    compDifference = uSum - cGuess;
}
if (userDifference >= compDifference)
{
    cout << "Computer wins!\n\n";
    compWins = compWins++;
    cout << userWins << " - " << compWins;
    cout << "\n\n";
}
else // userDifference < compDifference 
{
    cout << "You win!\n\n";
    userWins = userWins++;
    cout << userWins << " - " << compWins;
    cout << "\n\n";
}

}
```

Comment: I see no reason not to use a global variable here, the program is fairly small and procedural, it would be bad practice if this was a larger program but generally at that point you just move over to a more oop style anyway where you could encapsulate your trackers (which you could do anyway but I don't see the point for this code).

Comment: Create a class.

Comment: @deW1 I will have to look into that. Thank you for the responds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an algorithm:

```
unsigned int computer_wins = 0U;
unsigned int player_wins = 0U;
bool quit_the_game = false;
while (!quit_the_game)
{
  Prompt the user for input.
  if User wants to quit, break out of loop.
  Calculate computer's move.
  Determine winner.
  if (winner == computer) ++computer_wins;
  else ++player_wins;
}
Display player and computer wins.
```

The implementation is left as an exercise for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to answer with a more object oriented fashion, with some given tasks dedicated to given objects.

I did not go as far as I wanted so that my conception decisions are not optimum.
I had wished that human an AI inherit from the same player class (/interface), but I had to simplify due to lack of time.

Do not believe your exercice/homework is easy.

The code that should be OK ( did 1 manual edit after copy/paste from code::block). Feel free to comment if you have question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <limits>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

typedef uint32_t sum_type;

template<typename T> struct dice
{
    dice(T number_of_faces=6u):face_nb(number_of_faces){srand(time(0));};
    sum_type roll_Ktimes_n_sum(const uint8_t K)
    {
        double result;
        do {    result = 0;
                for(uint8_t i=0;i<K;++i) { result += roll();}
        } while ( numeric_limits<sum_type>::max() < result);
        return result;
    }
    virtual ~dice() = default;
private:
    T face_nb;
    T roll() { return (T) (((double)rand()/RAND_MAX)*(face_nb-1)+1.5); }
};

struct player
{
    static bool IsGameEnd;
    virtual sum_type guess(void) = 0;
    virtual void play(void) = 0;

protected:

    void referee_decision(double human, double machine, double winval)
    {
        double human_dist = fabs(human - winval);
        double AI_dist = fabs(machine - winval);

        if (human_dist  < AI_dist)  human_points++;
        if (AI_dist < human_dist)   AI_points++;

        cout << "Human: " << (int)human_points << " - AI: " << (int)AI_points << endl;
    }
private:
    static uint8_t human_points;
    static uint8_t AI_points;
};

bool player::IsGameEnd =  false;
uint8_t player::human_points = 0;
uint8_t player::AI_points = 0;

struct AI: private dice<uint8_t>, public player
{
    AI(uint8_t dices_number = 3):nb_dices(dices_number),human_number(0){};
    sum_type guess(void) { return roll_Ktimes_n_sum(nb_dices);}
    void play(void) { cout << "Please Human give number" << endl;
                      cin >> human_number;

                      if ( -1 == (int)human_number ) {IsGameEnd=true; return;}

                      sum_type machine_value = guess();
                      cout << "Machine guessed: " << machine_value << endl;

                      sum_type win_value = roll_Ktimes_n_sum(nb_dices);
                      cout << "Win value: " << win_value << endl;

                      referee_decision(human_number, machine_value, win_value);}

private:
   uint8_t nb_dices;
   sum_type human_number;
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

    AI ai;

    while(!player::IsGameEnd) ai.play();

    return 0;
}
```

Result is like following:

```
Hello world!
Please Human give number
10
Machine guessed: 7
Win value: 9
Human: 1 - AI: 0
Please Human give number
7
Machine guessed: 12
Win value: 8
Human: 2 - AI: 0
Please Human give number
3
Machine guessed: 17
Win value: 11
Human: 2 - AI: 1
Please Human give number
-1

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 20.366 s
Press any key to continue.
```